# How to find out the co-ordinate system using .prj file

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile

I'm very new to GIS concepts. Is there a way or procedure of finding out whether the co-ordinate system is in UTM, latitude/longitude or in stateplane using .prj file?

My .prj file contains the following text:

> GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS
>   84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check out Prj2EPSG [here](http://prj2epsg.org/search) for defination of your epsg.

> Prj2EPSG is a simple service for converting well-known text projection
>   information from .prj files into standard EPSG codes.

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 4):

The best reference I know to help you understand a .prj file is http://www.geoapi.org/3.0/javadoc/org/opengis/referencing/doc-files/WKT.html which explains the notation and should help you decode them.

Other resources include http://spatialreference.org which will allow you to look up and download .prj files for various projections. Another useful site is http://prj2epsg.org/search where you can convert .prj files to standard epsg codes which other software can understand.

In your specific example above it's lat/lon.